# rotation of a soccer ball comprising or pentagon and hexagons

Tags: group-theory

A soccer ball comprises of 20 faces that are regular hexagons and 12 faces that are regular pentagons.

Let G be the group of rotations acting on a set S of either the 20 regular hexagons or 12 regular pentagons.

WLOG, let the finite set S be the set of 12 regular pentagon. 
Under the orbit of the rotation elements/ permutation in G, any pentagons of indices $i=1,\cdot \cdot \cdot ,12$ can be mapped to any pentagons. 
Hence, the orbit of any regular pentagon $i$ under the permutations $\phi \in G$ is just the set S of 12 regular pentagons.

However, how do I determine the stabilisers of the regular pentagons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pentagon has five faces; it can be fixed, but rotated in five ways.
How many of these ways are symmetries of the football?

Comment: If we think of each pentagon as a 2D plane with the edges labeled j=1,2,3,4,5 with an axis through the centre of a pentagon; 5 consecutive rotation of 72 degrees in a single direction will map the any j, say j=1, back to j.
The position of the pentagon on the ball remains invariant under all permutations $\phi$

Comment: I should add that all five and only 5 permutation of the group of rotation fixes the indices of the pentagon. There are 5 stabilisers, thus.